# Running Java program from PowerShell starts a 64-bit JVM: From .bat file, starts 32-bit JVM

Tags: java, path

I am trying to start a Java application from a batch file, with a 2G heap size, like so:

```
java -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar cauldron-1.7.10-1.1236.05.212-server.jar nogui
```

When running this command from a batch file, Windows tries to start it using a 32-bit JVM which fails horribly, because a 2G heap is too big for a 32-bit JVM.

```
D:\directory>java -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar minecraft_server.1.7.10.jar nogui
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Adding the `-d64` flag to try and force a 64-bit JVM confirms that Windows is trying to start this in a 32-bit JVM.

```
D:\directory>java -d64 -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar minecraft_server.1.7.10.jar nogui
Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

Yet, when I run the exact same command from a PowerShell console, Windows decides to use the 64-bit Java and everything works fine.

I am guessing that the path variable is different for a batch file vs. a powershell console.

What is the root cause of this issue, how can I fix it, and how can I stop it happening again?

---

Addendum:

Output of `java -debug -version` from a batch file:

```
D:\directory>java -debug -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And from a PowerShell:

```
PS D:\ATLauncher_Hacking\install> java -debug -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Edit: Running `ECHO %PATH%` from a batch file - I see that `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` is on the path.